# data type for alphanumeric characters in hive

Tags: hive

how to set data type for alphanumeric characters in hive version (hive-0.12.0).

for ex: (10MA23423).

I've tried VARCHAR, VARCHAR2 but i'm getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Hive has a datatype called String. Try using that